# Double Timestamp with checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm absolutely new in programming and I found this solution which helps me stamping the date in a cell depending on a checkbox value. The problem is that I tried to copy the exact same code and changing the column from "C" to "D" and have both working the same way but either works on one or the other.

Sorry to bother, but I edit the question so its complete. I don't get exactly what to change!

```
/**  * This function is an auto-trigger, because of its name. It will be  * invoked on every change in the spreadsheet. The only change that
* we're interested in is in Column G, and we want to put a timestamp  * into Column J if the value selected for Column F is "VERDADERO".  */ function onEdit(event){   var ColG = 7;  // Column Number of "G"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();   if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColG) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column G
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColG+4);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
    switch (state) {
      case "TRUE":
      case true:
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      case "FALSE":
      case false:
        adjacent.clearContent();
        break;
      default:
        // Something we didn't expect
        adjacent.setValue("ERROR");
        break
    }   } } /**  * This function is an auto-trigger, because of its name. It will be  * invoked on every change in the spreadsheet. The only change that  * we're interested in is in Column C, and we want to put a timestamp  * into Column J if the value selected for Column F is "VERDADERO".  */ function onEdit(event){   var ColC = 3;  // Column Number of "C"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();   if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColC) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column C
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColC+7);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
    switch (state) {
      case "TRUE":
      case true:
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      case "FALSE":
      case false:
        adjacent.clearContent();
        break;
      default:
        // Something we didn't expect
        adjacent.setValue("ERROR");
        break
    }   } }
```

Both are the same, but I don't know what to change besides the columns numbers to make them both to work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution:

Change the name of your `onEdit` functions in such way that each of them have an unique name, i.e. `onEdit1` and `onEdit2`

Then add the following to your project

```
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1(e);
  onEdit2(e);
}
```

The above because if you use the same function name several times on the same scope, only one of the functions will work.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I will definitely try this solution!

Comment: @Agustin Have you tried the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi, I didnt know how to try it, but I solved it in another way! Thank you anyway!