# Google Sheets script not working if new script made for new sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I already have a script which is working fine in on sheet. But when I want a similar script working in another sheet. It won't work. Has anyone experienced such a thing before?

[image: New script seen with the name verkoop]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details. Ref. [ask].

Comment: i added details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue lines in the image points to two files, Code.gs and verkoop.gs. I think that is fair to say that by two scripts you mean that these files have the same functions (same name, same statements).

Functions in a Google Apps Script project should have unique names.

Related

- [Double Timestamp with checkbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/149454/88163)

Resources

- [Functions | MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)